# Get Total Number of Records after Distinct SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query that is joined to 3 tables. Without "DISTINCT" the total records is 331 but with Distinct the total number is 113. I want to get the 113 total only which is the total of distinct records. I used Count but it gives me the total number of not unique records. Please help me get the total of distinct records. Here's my query.

> Without distinct (331 records)

```
SELECT  
uf.OrigFileName,
uf.CreatedOn,
sdiTran.Status,
sdiFS.FileName,
sdiFile.ArchiveLogID,
COUNT(*) over() as totalRows
FROM [SDI].dbo.UploadedFile uf 
inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFile sdiFile on uf.UploadedFullFileName = sdiFile.OriginalName 
left join [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction sdiTran on sdiFile.ID = sdiTran.SDIFileID 
inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFSArchive sdiFS on sdiFile.ID = sdiFS.SDIFileID
WHERE uf.CommunityID = '7cc67de8-e5c2-4055-958b-f604c6a40cf1' 
AND uf.OrganizationID='e5750df1-0409-46b6-9aba-7f07be7c890c'
```

[image]

> After Distinct (113 records). totalRows should be 113 only since what I'm getting are distinct records.

```
SELECT distinct
uf.OrigFileName,
uf.CreatedOn,
sdiTran.Status,
sdiFS.FileName,
sdiFile.ArchiveLogID,
COUNT(*) over() as totalRows
FROM [SDI].dbo.UploadedFile uf 
inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFile sdiFile on uf.UploadedFullFileName = sdiFile.OriginalName 
left join [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction sdiTran on sdiFile.ID = sdiTran.SDIFileID 
inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFSArchive sdiFS on sdiFile.ID = sdiFS.SDIFileID
WHERE uf.CommunityID = '7cc67de8-e5c2-4055-958b-f604c6a40cf1' 
AND uf.OrganizationID='e5750df1-0409-46b6-9aba-7f07be7c890c'
```

[image]

Comment: Use `count(distinct some_unique_column) as totalRows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the distinct in a sub query:

```
SELECT *
    , COUNT(*) over() as totalRows
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    uf.OrigFileName,
    uf.CreatedOn,
    sdiTran.Status,
    sdiFS.FileName,
    sdiFile.ArchiveLogID
    FROM [SDI].dbo.UploadedFile uf 
    inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFile sdiFile on uf.UploadedFullFileName = sdiFile.OriginalName 
    left join [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction sdiTran on sdiFile.ID = sdiTran.SDIFileID 
    inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFSArchive sdiFS on sdiFile.ID = sdiFS.SDIFileID
    WHERE uf.CommunityID = '7cc67de8-e5c2-4055-958b-f604c6a40cf1' 
    AND uf.OrganizationID='e5750df1-0409-46b6-9aba-7f07be7c890c'
) A
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. By the way you have extra comma before FROM keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 331 rows with the count of 113 in each row, you can use a trick.  Use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows with the same values and then use a window function to count when the number is 1:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () as CountDistinct
FROM (SELECT uf.OrigFileName, uf.CreatedOn, sdiTran.Status, sdiFS.FileName, 
             sdiFile.ArchiveLogID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uf.OrigFileName, uf.CreatedOn, sdiTran.Status, sdiFS.FileName, sdiFile.ArchiveLogID
                              ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
      FROM [SDI].dbo.UploadedFile uf inner join
           [SDI].dbo.SDIFile sdiFile
           on uf.UploadedFullFileName = sdiFile.OriginalName left join
           [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction sdiTran
           on sdiFile.ID = sdiTran.SDIFileID inner join
           [SDI].dbo.SDIFSArchive sdiFS on sdiFile.ID = sdiFS.SDIFileID
      WHERE uf.CommunityID = '7cc67de8-e5c2-4055-958b-f604c6a40cf1' AND
            uf.OrganizationID='e5750df1-0409-46b6-9aba-7f07be7c890c'
     ) t;
```

If you only want the count of the distinct records, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  Because SQL Server doesn't allow multiple arguments, a subquery is perhaps the simplest method:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT uf.OrigFileName, uf.CreatedOn, sdiTran.Status, sdiFS.FileName, 
             sdiFile.ArchiveLogID
      FROM [SDI].dbo.UploadedFile uf inner join
           [SDI].dbo.SDIFile sdiFile
           on uf.UploadedFullFileName = sdiFile.OriginalName left join
           [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction sdiTran
           on sdiFile.ID = sdiTran.SDIFileID inner join
           [SDI].dbo.SDIFSArchive sdiFS on sdiFile.ID = sdiFS.SDIFileID
      WHERE uf.CommunityID = '7cc67de8-e5c2-4055-958b-f604c6a40cf1' AND
            uf.OrganizationID='e5750df1-0409-46b6-9aba-7f07be7c890c'
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use distinct in count() function with unique column,like  **select
   count(DISTINCT columnName) as count**.and don't use over() clause
   while getting count with distinct.

     -

### List item

```
SELECT  
uf.OrigFileName ,
uf.CreatedOn,
sdiTran.Status,
sdiFS.FileName,
sdiFile.ArchiveLogID,
COUNT(DISTINCT uf.OrigFileName) as totalRows
FROM [SDI].dbo.UploadedFile uf 
inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFile sdiFile on uf.UploadedFullFileName = sdiFile.OriginalName 
left join [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction sdiTran on sdiFile.ID = sdiTran.SDIFileID 
inner join [SDI].dbo.SDIFSArchive sdiFS on sdiFile.ID = sdiFS.SDIFileID
WHERE uf.CommunityID = '7cc67de8-e5c2-4055-958b-f604c6a40cf1' 
AND uf.OrganizationID='e5750df1-0409-46b6-9aba-7f07be7c890c'
```